# Declaring explicit type instead of var in select statement

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing the following request. It works as supposed to and returns data structured correctly. (It creates an element with "head" corresponding to the common field and puts the all elements of the same value in that field as a an Array in the "tail".)

```
var result
  = from A in As
    group A by A.F into B
    select new 
    {
      F1 = B.Key,
      F2 = from A in As
           where A.F == B.Key
           select A
    };
```

Now I'd like to declare it's type explicitly. I've checked in the debugger that my assumption on types is correct, however, when I try to declare that, it gives me conversion errors.

1. Why?
2. How can I declare the type explicitly?

I've tried different variant of declarations and *as* but failed.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<String, IEnumerable<MyType>>> result 
  = from ...
    } as Tuple<String, MyType>;
```

I know it's doable but I lack the experience to get it right. I've noticed that the following works. However, I'm not sure how to take it a step further, exchanging *Object* for the actual variable type.

```
IEnumerable<Object> result 
  = from ...
    } as Object;
```

Comment: The actual type is `IEnumerable<an_anonymous_type>` - you can't explicitly state the type of an anonymous type (it's anonymous!)

Comment: Why exactly do you want your code to be more complicated to maintain? This type of code is the exact reason `var` was added to C# and should be used.  Furthermore even if you can determine the type, if you ever change the code, the type likely would change also.

Comment: @Ramhound Client requirement. They need to get the data **including** the hard-typed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you know that the object "insides" are the same, C# is statically typed and resolves types based on their metadata (name, namespace...), not on their members. You select an anonymous type, not a `Tuple`, so the type resolver cannot "agree" with it being used as a `Tuple`.

If you hover over the `var` keyword in Visual Studio, it will tell you what type is it (because it must be known during compile time, unless it's a `dynamic`). However due to the fact you are using anonymous type, you will not be able to write the type explicitly - it has no name in the C# source code.

What you might do is either define the type elsewhere

```
internal class MyObj
{
    public MyObj(string head, IEnumerable<Foo> tail)
    {
        Head = head;
        Tail = tail;
    }

    public string Head { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Tail { get; set; }
}
```

and then use it in your query:

```
IEnumerable<MyObj> result
  = from A in As
    group A by A.F into B
    select new MyObj(
        B.Key,
        from A in As
        where A.F == B.Key
        select A);
```

or use a `Tuple` as Jon suggested **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14359066/1659828)**.

Comment: Can't see any reply from any "Jon"... :)

Comment: It works! However, now I get the fields in the *Tuple* typed variable to be called *Item1* and *Item2*. Is there a way to actually **name** them somehow?

Comment: That is unfortunately not possible. If you need those properties named, you have to specify your own full-fledged class/struct. Tuple is just a "visitor" from functional languages (like Haskell, Erlang...) where it serves as a lightweight way to group different data and it is often no different from lists - and as such you only have item positions/indexes, no names for them => hence Item1, Item2 and so on (in C#).

Answer (score 0):

The type of the enumerable sequence produced is determined by the type of the expression after the `select` clause, so:

```
select Tuple.Create(
    B.Key,
    (from A in As where A.F == B.Key select A).ToList()
)
```

Comment: Amazing! I got it to work thanks to your suggestion. However, I can't change the accepted status so I'll have to let it be on @HonzaBrestan for now. Also, I Believe that `ToString()` is suporfluous in this context.

Comment: Now I get the fields in the Tuple typed variable to be called *Item1* and *Item2*. Is there a way to actually **name** them somehow?

Comment: @CRMconfusee: No worries. Just saw your question about the `Item1` and `Item2` names -- if you want your own names you will have to define a new class to act as a vehicle for this information, just like Honza's answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

`Tuple<String, IEnumerable<MyType>> <=> Tuple<String, MyType>` this at first, but problem not here, you cant cast anonymous type to `Tuple`. You must explicitly define type then use it.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string F1 {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<MyType> F2 {get; set;}
} 

IEnumerable<YourClass> result
  = from A in As
    group A by A.F into B
    select new YourClass
    {
      F1 = B.Key,
      F2 = from A in As
           where A.F == B.Key
           select A
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating an anonymous type with the select new {... } you have to use var. There is no way to express the type explicitly.

Comment: How can I declare the piece so it isn't anonymous? I can't throw in `new Tupple<String,MyType>` because it's static and can't be instantiated.

Comment: It's Tuple, not Tupple. And yes you can. Use the static Tuple.Create()  to create the Tuple - it's nice because it infers the types.

Comment: Oh, **now** I see it. Damn my Swedish spelling! I'll remove my Tupe-Tuple comment because it doesn't make sense any more. You might want to remove your damn-comment too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't explicitly declare the type because by saying

```
select new {
   Member = Value
}
```

you're using an **anonymous type** - such types have unspeakable names and so this is one of the cases where you *must* use `var`.

Comment: How can I declare the piece so it isn't anonymous? I can't throw in `new Tupple<String,MyType>` because it's static and can't be instantiated.